# Receiving syntax error in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn python and I am receiving the error below and am unsure as to why. Please help a noob

```
# understanding how lists are stored
a = [5, 10]
b = a
print( "a: {}\t b: {}".format(a, b))
print( "Location a[0]: {}\t Location b[0]: {}".format( id(a[0], id(b[0])))
a[0] = 20              # re-declaring the value of a[0] also changes b[0]
print( "a: {}\t b: {}".format(a, b))
```

I'm receiving the following error but i pretty sure the syntax is correct

```
  File "<ipython-input-41-b19baf924839>", line 6
    a[0] = 20              # re-declaring the value of a[0] also changes b[0]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Missing closing bracket in line 5.

Comment: `id(a[0]` missing close paren

Comment: Generally, if you encounter a SyntaxError which doesn't make sense to you, search for the problem in the previous lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket in line 5: It should read

```
# understanding how lists are stored
a = [5, 10]
b = a
print( "a: {}\t b: {}".format(a, b))
print( "Location a[0]: {}\t Location b[0]: {}".format( id(a[0]), id(b[0])))
a[0] = 20              # re-declaring the value of a[0] also changes b[0]
print( "a: {}\t b: {}".format(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @justgoodin, you need a closing bracket at the end of line 5. You have 4 openings and only 3 closings.

Change to this:

```
print( "Location a[0]: {}\t Location b[0]: {}".format( id(a[0], id(b[0]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

now receiving

```
a: [5, 10]   b: [5, 10]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-f158d5c60d3e> in <module>
      3 b = a
      4 print( "a: {}\t b: {}".format(a, b))
----> 5 print( "Location a[0]: {}\t Location b[0]: {}".format( id(a[0], id(b[0]))))
      6 a[0] = 20              # re-declaring the value of a[0] also changes b[0]
      7 print( "a: {}\t b: {}".format(a, b))

TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: The formula looks wrong, try copying the above solution once again